# deleting cookie from parent domain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am in "foo.bar.com", I am setting the cookie with key "abc" for the domain ".bar.com"

So far so good.

Now, I am still in "foo.bar.com" but I want to delete the cookie with key "abc" from domain ".bar.com"

How do I do that? I am doing JavaScript.

Comment: As far as I know, this is only possible in PHP. I may be wrong. Also, deleting a cookie is just setting it to an expiration date before the current time.

Comment: How did you set the cookie?

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly provide the domain

```
document.cookie = 'abc=' + ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT ;domain=.foo.com;path=/";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `jquery.cookie`, you specify the domain and path:

```
$.removeCookie('cookie_name', {domain: '.food', path:'/'});
```

Comment: This isn't a popular comment, but it worked for me.  It allowed me to delete a cookie from .base.com from subsite.base.com

Answer (score 2):

While counter-intuitive, I've found the behavior seen by OP to be expected in both Chrome and Firefox. It's possible to create a cookie at a parent domain from a subdomain, but not possible to delete it afterward. [This answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18367855/12662876) describes this in a little more detail.